# Initialize materials on scene change in SceneKit (SwiftUI)

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, scenekit

I'm using SceneKit in my SwiftUI app to display some `.scn` files converted from `.dae` files exported from Blender.

The SceneKit is being displayed using `UIViewRepresentable`.

I'm displaying a step by step instructional guide, and each step contains some text and an animation. Each animation is its own `.scn` file and I'm swapping the scene file based on the current step.

My issue is I need to perform some initialisation of materials when the scene is swapped but only `updateUIView` is called when this happens, and I don't want to be doing this work here as this gets called each time the animation is paused etc.

I want to be doing this work once each time the scene is replaced but I'm struggling to find a solution to this with my current implementation.

I'm thinking the way I'm handling this scene swapping is incorrect but I'm wondering if someone can point me in the right direction.

Thanks!

See full code below:

```swift
struct MaintenanceFlowDetailView: View {

    var maintenanceFlow: MaintenanceFlow
    @State private var currentStepIndex = 0
    @State private var pauseAnimation = false

    func stepBackwards() {
        currentStepIndex -= 1
        pauseAnimation = false
    }

    func stepForwards() {
        currentStepIndex += 1
        pauseAnimation = false
    }

    func togglePauseAnimation() {
        pauseAnimation = !pauseAnimation
    }

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 12){
                SceneKitView(sceneFilePath: maintenanceFlow.steps[currentStepIndex].scenePath, pauseAnimation: $pauseAnimation)
                    .frame(height: 300)
                Text(maintenanceFlow.steps[currentStepIndex].text)
                Spacer()
                HStack{
                    if currentStepIndex > 0 {
                        Button(action: stepBackwards) {
                            Text("Back")
                        }
                    }
                    Spacer()
                    Button(action: togglePauseAnimation) {
                        Text(pauseAnimation ? "Play" : "Pause")
                    }
                    Spacer()
                    if currentStepIndex < maintenanceFlow.steps.count - 1 {
                        Button(action: stepForwards) {
                            Text("Next")
                        }
                    }

                }
            }.padding()
            .navigationBarTitle(Text(maintenanceFlow.name))
        }

    }
}

struct SceneKitView : UIViewRepresentable {

    var sceneFilePath: String
    @Binding var pauseAnimation: Bool

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> SCNView {

        print("calling CREATE view")

        // I NEED TO INITIALISE MATERIALS ETC JUST ONCE HERE...

        let scnView = SCNView()
        return scnView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ scnView: SCNView, context: Context) {
        print("calling UPDATE view")

        // BUT THE SCENE IS REPLACED HERE :(

        let scene = SCNScene(named: sceneFilePath)!
        scene.isPaused = pauseAnimation
        scnView.scene = scene

        scnView.showsStatistics = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following:

```
struct SceneKitView : UIViewRepresentable {

    var sceneFilePath: String
    @Binding var pauseAnimation: Bool

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> SCNView {

        print("calling CREATE view")

        let scnView = SCNView()
        let scene = SCNScene(named: sceneFilePath)

        scnView.scene = scene
        scnView.showsStatistics = true
        return scnView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ scnView: SCNView, context: Context) {
        print("calling UPDATE view")
        scnView.scene?.isPaused = pauseAnimation
    }
}
```

**Update:** a bit corrected, but idea is the same. Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4. `SceneKitView` is recreated when `sceneFilePath:` is changed, so if it is not updated, then it is different code issue.

Here is testing view used:

```
struct TestSceneKitView: View {
    @State private var filePath = "test1"
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Push") { self.filePath = "test2" }
            SceneKitView(sceneFilePath: filePath, pauseAnimation: .constant(false))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Asperi. However, this now results in the scene not being switched when the index is changed.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I have copied and pasted your new code and only "calling UPDATE view" is printed when Push is clicked. Are you seeing "calling CREATE view" printed??

Comment: @Tappyy. yes, I do.

Comment: I was running Xcode 11.3 so I updated to 11.4.1 and still no luck. I copied your code into its own file and debug preview and still only see "calling UPDATE view" when clicking Push :/